# Vector bundles with structure groups $G_2$ and $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles, spin-geometry

As is stated for example in this post ([Structures on Vector Bundles with Reduced Structure Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592279/structures-on-vector-bundles-with-reduced-structure-group)), we can impose interesting restrictions on real vector bundles by demanding their transition functions to lie in certain subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}(n)$; for example if they are contained in $\operatorname{GL}^+(n)$, the respective bundles must be orientable; if they are in $\operatorname{U}(n)\subset \operatorname{GL}(2n)$, they are complex vector bundles with a Hermitian scalar product, and for $\operatorname{SU}(n)\subset \operatorname{GL}(2n)$, the determinant bundle must even be trivial.

However, we can also restrict our attention to vector bundles with transition functions in one of the more "exceptional" subgroups $G_2 \subset \operatorname{GL}(7)$ and $\operatorname{Spin}(7) \subset \operatorname{GL}(8)$. Are there also such nice descriptions of these bundles? According to Wikipedia, a manifold $M$ has a tangent bundle with transition functions choosable in $G_2$ iff it is a $7$-dimensional Spin-Manifold, but I couldn't find any literature on the general case. Has anyone else encountered something that could help?